# Formatting data into Json to be consumed by Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json

I am trying to add data into jquery Datatable using Ajax. Here is my server side code in c#

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetColumnName(string applicationName)
    {
        var cName = new columnName
        {         
           dbcolumnName = "Name",
           CustcolumnName = "Holder Name"            
        };

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(cName);

        return json;
    }
}

public class columnName
{
    public string dbcolumnName { get; set; }
    public string CustcolumnName { get; set; }
}
```

and here is how I am trying to use in Jquery Datatable.

```
success: function OnSuccess(response) {
data = eval(response.d);
console.log(data);

 $('#SettingsDatatable').dataTable({
    "order": [],
    "columnDefs": [{
    "className": "dt-center", "orderable":   false, "width": 20, 'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'
    + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
   }
   }],
   "processing": true,
   "data": data.cName
 });
```

With the above code, I am not able to populate data in Jquery Datatable.I am getting an error as `0x800a03ec - JavaScript runtime error: Expected ';'` at `data = eval(response.d);`

Comment: Are you definitely closing the `OnSuccess` function? I can't seem to find a close for it. Might be creating a false error because the function isn't closed.

Comment: @Dandy Yes , its closing